# Facing NFS file transfer issue, file gets truncated

Tags: linux, nfs

I am getting this error while transferring files using NFS, and the file size is getting truncated

Can anyone give me a hint? We tried 2GB, and the file gets truncated at 400 MB.

```
Jun 20 11:09:22 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2501.169697] nfsd: SETATTR(3)  20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000 
Jun 20 11:09:22 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2501.169704] nfsd: fh_verify(20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000) 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.682093] nfsd_dispatch: vers 3 proc 7 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.682105] nfsd: WRITE(3)    20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000 524288 bytes at 0 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.682112] nfsd: fh_verify(20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000) 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.690670] nfsd_dispatch: vers 3 proc 7 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.690684] nfsd: WRITE(3)    20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000 524288 bytes at 524288 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.690693] nfsd: fh_verify(20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000) 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.694520] nfsd: non-standard errno: -16 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.696118] nfsd_dispatch: vers 3 proc 7 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.696174] nfsd: WRITE(3)    20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000 524288 bytes at 1048576 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.696180] nfsd: fh_verify(20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000) 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.696512] nfsd: write complete host_err=524288 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.700571] nfsd: non-standard errno: -16 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.704554] nfsd_dispatch: vers 3 proc 7 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.704568] nfsd: WRITE(3)    20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000 524288 bytes at 1572864 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.704576] nfsd: fh_verify(20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000) 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.708904] nfsd_dispatch: vers 3 proc 7 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.708913] nfsd: WRITE(3)    20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000 524288 bytes at 2097152 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.708919] nfsd: fh_verify(20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000) 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.712200] nfsd_dispatch: vers 3 proc 7 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.712209] nfsd: WRITE(3)    20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000 524288 bytes at 2621440 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.712215] nfsd: fh_verify(20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000) 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.715398] nfsd_dispatch: vers 3 proc 7 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.715408] nfsd: WRITE(3)    20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000 524288 bytes at 3145728 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.715415] nfsd: fh_verify(20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000) 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.715533] nfsd: non-standard errno: -16 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.719462] nfsd: non-standard errno: -16 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.720902] nfsd_dispatch: vers 3 proc 7 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.720913] nfsd: WRITE(3)    20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000 524288 bytes at 3670016 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.720920] nfsd: fh_verify(20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000) 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.724749] nfsd_dispatch: vers 3 proc 7 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.724760] nfsd: WRITE(3)    20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000 524288 bytes at 4194304 
Jun 20 11:09:26 ServerIFM33 kernel: [ 2504.724766] nfsd: fh_verify(20: 81010001 00000001 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000000)
```

Answer (score 2):

What do the logs on the other side say?  I suspect the other side is having a problem (the file system is full, doesn't support large files, etc.)

According to /usr/include/errno.h  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503878/how-to-know-what-the-errno-means)

```
#define EBUSY       16  /* Device or resource busy */
```

NFS errors and errno.h codes are only the same for the first few numbers. By the time you get up to 16, they are unrelated.  However, this is often a clue. http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/NFSKernelErrorExplained

(P.S.  While Googling about this, I found an interesting article that probably isn't related: http://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/454214-SOLVED-ata1-SRST-failed-(errno-16)-boot-extremely-slow-BIOS-disappears )